# DIMENSION definition within a subroutine

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to figure out what (if at all) is the difference between the following definitions of variables (i.e. in subroutine/function interface)

```
CALL example(RealVar)
```

where the definition of the dummy variable within the subroutine in the one case would be:

```
SUBROUTINE example(var)
   REAL(wp), INTENT(<IN/OUT/INOUT>) :: var(0:n)
   ...
```

And in another case:

```
SUBROUTINE example(var)
   REAL(wp), INTENT(<IN/OUT/INOUT>), DIMENSION(0:n) :: var
   ...
```

1. Is there any difference between the definitions?
2. Will the compiler treat it any differently?
3. Is this just a backwards-compatibility thing?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I did not manage to find the "original" question before (didn't know how to formulate the search correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is there any difference? No

2) Will the compiler treat it any differently? Almost certainly not

3) Backwards compatibility? Sort of but not really!

Personally I prefer the second form, but it's purely stylistic,

Ian